# Flink job - continously running vs cancel/start

Tags: apache-flink

What is the benefit in terms of compute resources in suspend or restarting a Flink job as needed vs continuously running it? This is for use cases where new files arrive daily and are ingested within an hour. These jobs are running continuously now. But would like to know any best practices around such use cases, so that compute can be optimized on migration to cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be running in the cloud, then spinning up a Flink cluster as-needed (once/day) to do batch processing of the day's input files is obviously going to save you money, and (likely) be operationally easier, versus running a true streaming job.

Answer (score 0):

> This is for use cases where new files arrive daily and are ingested within an hour.

Given to this situation, batch execution mode is better than streaming execution mode.

Streaming execution mode works best for the scenario like real-time computing, monitoring, in-time recommendation, and etc. Batch execution mode works best for the scenario like processing data once or daily.

Furthermore, Flink has applied several optimizations for batch execution mode based on the condition that the input stream is bounded.

To enable batch execution mode you can check more details at the official documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/

Comment: Ok, will check using batch mode. But the job would still be continuously running on batch mode? Maybe we need to use batch mode for the daily files (bounded sources) along with spinning up a cluster for the batch processing.

Comment: Batch job will terminate once all the bounded input data has been dealt with. The job won't be continuously running. If you want to run the job daily, you can simply use crontab, or considering establish a platform to control your daily jobs.

Comment: Ok though one advantage with continuously running is no need to manage crontab, and also takes care of file arrival delays, as the job is always monitoring.